# PHP using a variable inside do_shortcode() - Wordpress Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The format for the shortcode that I wish to do is: [product id="id#"]
The format for do_shortcode is: do_shortcode('[shortcode');

My question is how can I insert a PHP variable as the id#?

I have a variable $itemid that I would like to use like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[product id="$itemid"])
```

But I cannot for the life of me get it to work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `echo do_shortcode("[product id='.$itemid.']")` ?

Comment: Could you share your `add_shortcode` function for `product` ?

Answer (score 10):

This is an issue of single quotes vs double quotes,

see [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

this fix should work:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product id=\"$itemid\"]")
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
$short = '[product id="'.$itemid.'"]';
echo do_shortcode($short);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your custom `shortcode` using [`add_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) function,

```
function products($id) {
    print_r($id);
}
add_shortcode( 'product', 'products' );


$itemid = "132";
```

**concatenate** the `$itemid` in `do_shortcode` function like below

```
echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$itemid.'"]');
```

Output

```
Array ( [id] => 132 )
```